# Android - Expand groups in a Listview only on a long click

Tags: java, android, listview

In my ExpandableListView I have 6 groups with multiple childs. I want to expand a group only if the user makes a longclick on this group. So I tried it with the OnItemLongClickListener:

```
    @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            long packedPosition = expListView.getExpandableListPosition(position);

            int itemType = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(packedPosition);
            int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition);
            int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(packedPosition);

            /* if group item clicked */
            if (itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
                // ...
                onGroupLongClick(groupPosition);
            }

            // /* if child item clicked */
            else if (itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                // ...
                onChildLongClick(groupPosition, childPosition);
            }

            return false;
        }
```

It doesn't work. The groups are still expanding on a normal click.
Is it the wrong Listener? But there is no onGroupLongClickListener.